# DevExpress Xtrareport unbound detail report data source

Tags: xtrareport

I'm using DevExpress Xtrareport  in my report i am using three unbounded detail reports 
my question 
How can i set the data source and data adapter for each one of these reports by code

Comment: my question  too difficult ?

Comment: Have you got solution for your question